# vue js how to get notified when any property's value is being read?

Tags: vue.js

i'm working in vue js and i'm trying to achieve something which has dependency. Actually inside data i have a property of boolean, what i want is that whenever this property's value is being used or this property is accessed i'm get notified so that i'm able to change other properties before this property's value getting used.

```html
<template>
    <!-- <v-card> -->
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent
      height="100%"
      style="border:1px solid black;"
    >
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>

        <v-btn
          icon
          @click.stop="changeMiniValue()"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          link
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  <!-- </v-card> -->
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        drawer: true,
        items: [
          { title: 'Home', icon: 'mdi-home-city' },
          { title: 'My Account', icon: 'mdi-account' },
          { title: 'Users', icon: 'mdi-account-group-outline' },
        ],
        mini:this.getMini(),
      }
    },
    methods:{
        changeMiniValue(){
            this.mini=!this.mini;
            this.$store.dispatch('changeMini',!this.$store.state.mini);
            
        },
        getMini(){
            this.$store.dispatch('changeColsToMin','9');
            console.log('method executed');
            return this.$store.state.mini;
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.$store.dispatch('changeColsToMin','11');
        this.mini=this.$store.state.mini;
    },
    // computed:{
    //     getMiniValueCompute(){
    //         this.$store.dispatch('changeColsToMin','9');
    //         return this.$store.state.mini;
    //     }
    // }
}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: You can use getters and setters, however, there is probably a less complicated solution. Please provide a snippet and explain your issue.

Comment: Hi Nomi welcome to SO - please provide a snippet to your code. With `getting used` you mean whenever the value to this property is changed, right ? There are a few options but it would probably depend on more background, what's your use-case exactly ?

Comment: i updated the question and added to code. now you see in start of code :mini-variant="mini" so when ever mini is being read so that i will change other values

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possibile solution: create an "hidden" field and expose it through computed properties, with your custom logic.

```js
<script>
export default {
   data () {
      return {
         _mini: false
      }
   },
   methods: {
       // Your methods here...
   },
   computed: {
      mini {
         get: function () {
            // TODO: notify your listeners, functions, etc.

            return this._mini;
         },
         set: function (value) {
            this._mini = mini;
         }
      }
   }
}
</script>
```